# CompiledFunction::ctfa - Argument should be a rank 4 tensor of machine-size real number

Tags: compile, tensors, data-types

Dear Mathematica community,

I got the following error line:

> CompiledFunction::ctfa "Argument {<<1>>} at position 1 should be a rank 4 tensor of machine-size real number"

This is my function:

```
wComplete = Compile[{{structure, _Real, 4}, {Istructure, _Real, 
 1}, {gravvec, _Real, 1}}, 

  Module[{xMin, yMin, zMin, ToSort, Sorted, vector1, vector2,vector3, w1, w2, w3},

   {xMin, yMin, zMin} = findMinAndPlot[structure, Istructure, gravvec, 0][[2]];
   {Eigenval, Eigenvec} = Eigensystem[HesseRealGab[xMin, yMin, zMin, structure, Istructure]];

   {w1, w2, w3} = Sqrt[Eigenval/m ];
   {w1, w2, w3}
  ],
  {{Eigenval, _Real, 1}, {Eigenvec, _Real,2}}, 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];
```

I call the function with the following tensors (ranks should fit):

> structure = {{{{7/500000,1/50000,441/500000},...},...},...}
>
> Istructure = {1,1,-1,-2,3.5}
>
> gravvec = {0,0,0}
>
> wComplete[structure,Istructure,gravvec]

I think that structure is a tensor of rank 4, so I can't understand the error message.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `ArrayQ[structure, 4, NumberQ]` return?

Comment: @CarlWoll It returns false, so it seems not to be a rank 4 tensor of machine-size real numbers. I think the problem is that the length of the entries is not the same overall. It look more like this: {{a,b},{c,d,e}}. How can I work with this?